# Youtube live streaming starts from beginning all the time on android tablets

Tags: android, youtube-api, tablet

We are using Youtube Api for android devices to play live streaming videos and it is totally working on mobile devices but on Android tablets the live video starts from beginning. It is not for a specific tablet, this problem is shown for more than 1 tablets that has android operating system. We already tried from those devices (Lenovo Smart Tab II , Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1)

Comment: Is this happening on player API or iframe?

Comment: it is happening on player API